# jquery load() firing only once when there's multiple elements that fire it

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to fire a jquery plugin when all the images in a DIV are loaded. To do that I use the following piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fullwidth-content img").load(function() {
        $('#fullwidth-content img').capty();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the plugin call is fired for every time an image is loaded. So if this page has 5 images, it will fire 5 times. How can I get this to fire only once? It is very important that it waits for the images to be loaded..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#fullwidth-content img').capty();
});
```

$(document).ready fires after the DOM is loaded, $(window).load fires after all elements (graphic included) are loaded

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/